# Shopify metafields AJAX call to get object data as a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I have been trying for hours to figure out how to get Shopify product metafields as variables when I am constructing a compare products page.

I can get the product, and I can get the metafields now. The issue is making the metafields available outside the AJAX call.

I can push the metafields object to an array, but I cannot seem to access any of the keys within the array for some reason.

Code below. The product in the first function is actually the product ID.

```
function singleProductCall(product) {
  //get all products in store (via AJAX) and filter
  jQuery.getJSON(`/products.json`, function(response) {
    let all_products = response.products;
    const keep = parseInt(product, 10);

    single_product = all_products.filter(obj => obj.id == keep);

    single_product.forEach(product => {
      let iter =
        document.querySelectorAll('#compareContainer .compare-box').length + 1;

      let fields = getMetafields(product);

      console.log('as variable', fields);

      createCompareItem(product, iter, fields);
    });
    initAccordion()
  });
}
function getMetafields(product) {
  let fields = [];

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/products/${product.handle}?view=metafields`,
    success: function(response) {
      metafields = JSON.parse(response);
      fields.push(metafields);
      console.log('within ajax', metafields);
    },
    error: function(status) {
      console.warn('ERROR', status);
    }
  });
  return fields;
}
```

And here is the createCompareItem function, where I want to use the metafield values.

```
function createCompareItem(product, iter, fields) {
  $('#compareContainer').append(`
    <div id="compare-${
      product.id
    }" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1-3 compare-box pure-box">
      <div class="box-${iter}">
        <div class="compare-box-header">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x60.png" alt="${
            product.title
          }" class="product-name" />
        </div>
        <div class="green-box-container">
          <div class="accordion accordion-hide-first product-features-accordion">

            <h2>The Rundown</h2>
            <div class="content">
              <p>${product.title}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Key Features</h2>
            <div class="content">
              <p>${product.id}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Benefits</h2>
            <div class="content">
              <p>${product.handle}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Ingredients</h2>
            <div class="content">
              <p>${product.url}</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Amino Acids</h2>
            <div class="content">

              <div class="chart">
                <div class="chart-left">Alanine</div>
                <div class="chart-right">0.900g</div>   
              </div>

              <div class="chart">
                <div class="chart-left">Alanine</div>
                <div class="chart-right">0.900g</div>   
              </div>

              <div class="chart">
                <div class="chart-left">Alanine</div>
                <div class="chart-right">0.900g</div>   
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick="removeCompare(${
        product.id
      })" class="button"><i class="button-left"></i><span>Remove</span><i class="button-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  `);
}
```

Currently the fields variable is returning an array with a single object in it, which contains the metafield keys and values.  However I am having trouble accessing the keys and values.

Any help is appreciated as I have been at this for a while and can't find a solution!!

Comment: What is the response in `/products/${product.handle}?view=metafields` ? Is it proper?

Comment: And what is it that you're trying to do here? `const keep = parseInt(product, 10);`

Comment: Why are you using Javascript at all here. Just use Liquid. That is what it is for. This use case has zero need for JS. Remove all your problems by choosing the better tool for the job as they say...

Comment: @DavidLazar the page needs to respond to user actions ex. choosing a product from a drop down. If there is a way to achieve this using liquid I am all for it. My understanding is that liquid only loads when the page loads and cannot be used/called with user actions.

Comment: Anything you render in a drop down that gives the user choice, for example, other products, can be rendered in Liquid. You know ahead of time what the choices are. You have to limit yourself to realistic uses of JS here.